# Xcode 13 and 13.1 crashing on launch

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode crashes when opening xcworkspace which has more than 150 targets.

Following solutions have been tried:

1. Writing main thread command on terminal
2. Deleting derived data
3. Deleting xcuserdata inside the xcworkspace content
4. Restarting mac multiple times
5. deleted whole xcode folder from ~Library/ folder
6. Deleted cache

Below is the terminal logs when opening xcode which end up in abort.

```
Process:               Xcode [6005]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               13.1 (19466)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-19466000000000000~20 (13A1030d)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       844664792
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-10-28 12:51:35.1892 +0530
OS Version:            macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     6.0 (19P548)
Anonymous UUID:        3118C151-62B2-F809-F9A0-A23CD9A811EA

Sleep/Wake UUID:       7154F81D-4FC6-4A00-98DD-F582CF444EF5

Time Awake Since Boot: 11000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       5917 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        2  Dispatch queue: <IDEXCBuildSupport.IDEXCBuildServiceBuildOperation:0x7fa8fdca4d50:REfc>-builder-queue (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Thread 2 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: <IDEXCBuildSupport.IDEXCBuildServiceBuildOperation:0x7fa8fdca4d50:REfc>-builder-queue (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff806242112 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff806278233 pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7ff8061c4d10 abort + 123
3   IDEKit                                 0x10a56cb18 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1233
4   IDEKit                                 0x10a56df62 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleUncaughtException:] + 880
5   IDEKit                                 0x10a56e12d IDEHandleUncaughtException + 94
6   DVTFoundation                          0x109d3b491 DVTSyncPerformBlock + 480
7   XCBuildSupport                         0x14690dbf7 closure #1 in IDEXCBuildServiceBuildOperation.addOperations(to:) + 231
8   XCBuildSupport                         0x14690558e thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 14
9   Foundation                          0x7ff807187592 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
10  Foundation                          0x7ff80718748a -[NSBlockOperation main] + 98
11  Foundation                          0x7ff807187421 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 17
12  Foundation                          0x7ff80718668f -[NSOperation start] + 785
13  Foundation                          0x7ff807186365 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 17
14  Foundation                          0x7ff80718623a __NSOQSchedule_f + 182
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff8060ced0d _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 83
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff8060c1cc9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff8060c4746 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 460
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff8060c3ded _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 716
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff8060d13ba _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 343
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff8060d1b5a _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 160
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff806275049 _pthread_wqthread + 256
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80627401b start_wqthread + 15

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.9G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.9G(100%)
Writable regions: Total=2.5G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=2.5G(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               512K        4 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG image                          1696K       71 
ColorSync                          244K       28 
CoreAnimation                     13.7M      193 
CoreData                            12K        1 
CoreGraphics                        12K        2 
CoreImage                           44K       11 
CoreUI image data                 2852K       25 
Dispatch continuations            64.0M        1 
Foundation                         540K        2 
Image IO                           544K       24 
JS JIT generated code              1.0G        3 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                             1.4G     1366 
MALLOC guard page                   48K       12 
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)           4096K        4         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Performance tool data                4K        1         not counted in TOTAL below
SQLite page cache                  320K        5 
STACK GUARD                       56.1M       26 
Stack                             20.7M       26 
VM_ALLOCATE                         48K        9 
WebKit Malloc                     3176K        7 
__CTF                               759        1 
__DATA                            78.2M     1025 
__DATA_CONST                      49.4M      734 
__DATA_DIRTY                      2402K      268 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       895.0M      297 
__OBJC_RO                         81.5M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         3120K        3 
__TEXT                             1.0G      974 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
dyld private memory               1024K        1 
libnetwork                        1152K       16 
mapped file                      199.2M      186 
shared memory                      784K       19 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              4.8G     5349 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     4.8G     5349
```

Comment: Have you tried from different computers? Maybe with more RAM?

Comment: @ArikSegal we have already tried on different computers with 16GB ram, still no luck.

Comment: Can you try Xcode 12.x?  I found that some codebases (SwiftUI based) cause a massive amount of load to process the code on Xcode 13 but work without a problem on xcode12.  It was a problem with the type inference process in Swift.  Given you have a lot of targets, maybe this makes the problem magnified.  Can you reduce the number of targets as an experiment?

Comment: @FaisalMemon I tried with 1 target but still, it's crashing.